# Deleting rows in a r table with less than 3 observations

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to remove rows in a data frame with less than 3 observations. Let me explain the matter in a better way. 
I have a dataframe with 6 indipendent variables and 1 dependent. As I'm doing a density plot in `ggplot2` using faceting, variables with less than 3 observations are not plotted (obviously). I'm looking for a way to delete these rows with less than 3 observations. this is an example of the data:

```
'data.frame':   432 obs. of  6 variables:
$ ID        : Factor w/ 439 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Forno     : Factor w/ 8 levels "Micro","Macro",..: 1 1 1 6 6 6 4 4 4 5 ...
$ Varieta: Factor w/ 11 levels "cc","dd",..: 11 11 11 6 6 6 1 1 1 6 ...
$ Impiego: Factor w/ 5 levels "aperto","chiuso",..: 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 5 ...
$ MediaL    : num  60.7 58.9 60.5 55.9 56.1 ...
$ MediaL.sd : num  4.81 4.79 4.84 5.27 5.64 ...
```

ggplot code:

```
ggplot(d1,aes(MediaL))+geom_density(aes(fill=Varieta),colour=NA,alpha=0.5)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+facet_grid(Forno~Impiego)+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+theme_mio +xlim(45,65)+
    stat_bin(geom="text",aes(y=0,label=..count..),size=2,binwidth=2)
```

I would like to remove all the interactions with less than 3 observations.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the actual output of your sample data would be useful. You can provide this via `dput(yourObject)` instead of the text representation you provided. However, it does seem like the same basic approach below works equally well with a `matrix`, `data.frame`, and `table` data structure.

```
#Matrix
x <- matrix(c(5,4,4,3,1,5,1,8,2), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
x[x < 3] <- NA
#----
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    4
[2,]    3   NA    5
[3,]   NA    8   NA

#data.frame
xd <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(5,4,4,3,1,5,1,8,2), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
xd[xd < 3] <- NA
#----
  V1 V2 V3
1  5  4  4
2  3 NA  5
3 NA  8 NA

#Table. Simulate some data first
set.seed(1)
samp <- data.frame(x1 = sample(c("acqua", "fango", "neve"), 20, TRUE),
                   x2 = sample(c("pippo", "pluto", "paperino"), 20, TRUE))
x2 <-table(samp)
x2[x2 < 3] <- NA
#----
       x2
x1      paperino pippo pluto
  acqua                    3
  fango        3            
  neve               3     3
```

ggplot generally likes data to be in long format, most often achieved via the `melt()` command in `reshape2`. If you provide your plotting code, that may illustrate a better way to remove the data you don't want to plot.

Comment: now you have the ggplot script. I would like to remove the rows from the dataframe.

Comment: You're still not completely to a reproducible example. You would need to add the data you use to make your plot. Please see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. My guess is that you should probably be able to put 2 and 2 together with what I have above and your code, If not - come back with a specific question on where you are stuck.